# Set SSH timeout in Amazon EC2 instance - CentOS 7

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I'm using CentOS 7 and trying to set time-out to 15 sec

in  /etc/ssh/sshd_config set

```
ClientAliveInterval 15
TCPKeepAlive no
ClientAliveCountMax 1
```

restarted sshd service but SSH session is active after 15 sec

added also

```
TMOUT=15 to /etc/profile
```

but still nothing

Answer (score 2):

After lot of googling found it out:

/etc/ssh/sshd_config has no any effect, it's meant for when the connection between the ssh client and the ssh server become unresponsive

```
cat /etc/profile.d/ssh-timeout.sh
export TMOUT=15
readonly TMOUT
```

and reboot